# How to create Indefinite number of CSS div's from fetched data in my Mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I was recently working with PHP while loop and I found that there's no question related to the following topic that:

How can we create an indefinite numbers of div's from MySQL database and as well insert image in it using PHP.

And if it is there. There's no convenient way to perform.

So, I decided to share the way I found most convenient to work with this.

To do so I have created a table with the following columns:

```
+-------------------+
| ID | Name | Image |
+-------------------+
```

So you can find the code in the answer.

Comment: This seems to be a trivial use of a while loop. I see nothing novel about either the problem or its solution.

Comment: What do you mean by this? I am just helping the developers like me who always get confuse between which answer to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
        $host = '';
        $user = '';
        $pass = '';
        $db = '';
        $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db); 
        $result = $mysqli->query 
        ("SELECT * FROM your_table_name") 
        or die($mysqli->error); 
      ?> 
      <div class='main'> 
        <?php
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): 
        ?> 
        <div class='container'>
          <img class="item_image" src='<?php echo $row['Image'] ?>'>
          <p class="text_main_head"><b><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></b></p>
</p>
        </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```